# shell script only runs as desired in certain directories

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I am writing a bourne shell script that essentially has the same functionality as ls.

Here is my code.

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "\n"                               

if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]
then
    SEARCH_DIR=`pwd`
fi

if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]
then
    SEARCH_DIR=$1
    if [ ! -d "$SEARCH_DIR" ]
    then
        echo "Directory Does Not Exist - - - Exiting"
        echo "\n"
        exit
    fi
fi

DIR_CONTENT=`ls $SEARCH_DIR`    

for file in $DIR_CONTENT
do
    if [ -f "$file" ]         
    then
    echo "f\c"
    fi

    if [ -d "$file" ]         
    then
        echo "d\c"
    fi

    if [ ! -f "$file" ] && [ ! -d "$file" ] 
    then
        echo "-\c"
    fi

    if [ -r "$file" ]         
    then
        echo "r\c"
    else                
        echo "-\c"
    fi

    if [ -w "$file" ]         
    then
        echo "w\c"
    else                
        echo "-\c"
    fi

    if [ -x "$file" ]    
    then
        echo "x\c"
    else                
        echo "-\c"
    fi

    echo ' \c'              
    echo "$file"              


done
    echo "\n"
```

When I execute the script, I get the desired output for that specific directory:
For example:

```
$ ./dirinfo


dirinfo version 0.1


drwx Desktop
frwx dirinfo
frw- #dirinfo#
frwx dirinfo~
frwx dirinfo2~
```

But if I try to pass an argument for a different directory the script doesn't seem to acknowledge my if statements.

For example:

```
$ ./dirinfo /bin


dirinfo version 0.1


---- bash
---- bunzip2
---- busybox
---- bzcat
---- bzcmp
```

But if I execute the script from the /bin directory I get the desired effect:

```
$ cd /bin    
$ ~/dirinfo


dirinfo version 0.1


fr-x bash
fr-x bunzip2
fr-x busybox
fr-x bzcat
fr-x bzcmp
```

Could someone please attempt to point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as user430051 mentioned you are running it from a directory and listing files from another which will not work.

solution is prepend you search dir before filename like,

```
for file in $DIR_CONTENT
do
    file="$SEARCH_DIR/$file"
    if [ -f "$file" ]         
    then
    echo "f\c"
    fi
```

and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This solved the issue. When I was originally writing it I thought it was strange that file was never really defined, but didn't think anymore of it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Dont have a bash to test right now, but maybe $file doesnt have the full path so, evaluating -r or -w would not work. When you cd to destination directory, files are on ./.

Comment: That's exactly it. When OP sets DIR_CONTENT it gets the names of the files without the path. OP should run `ls /bin' to see output, then try `stat`ing first file in list in order to understand.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many ways to solve your problem but the simplest solution would be to add one line which is missing (i.e cd "$SEARCH_DIR"), just add it in your script after DIR_CONTENT=`ls $SEARCH_DIR` and your script is good to go as per your expectation.

The main difference in this solution and above given by Nachiket is that in my solution file names in output will not have absolute path which I guess is your expectation.

```
DIR_CONTENT=`ls $SEARCH_DIR`    

cd "$SEARCH_DIR"

for file in $DIR_CONTENT
do
    if [ -f "$file" ]
```